# in Notepad ++, add the text of each line at the end of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

*In **Notepad++** how to:*

***`Add all characters at the end of each line after adding the equal sign "=".`***

*For **example**:*

```
This is a text
```

*to*

```
This is a text = This is a text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
(.+)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1 = \1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sX9vW1/4)

Answer (score 2):

```
(.+)\K
```

Try this. Replace by  `= \1`

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/78)

Comment: Tea with milk D:< come on!

Comment: Here . . . from Spain

Comment: Nice to hear that . . .